# Buttons in log in screen don't work

Tags: login, 20.04, login-screen, bug-reporting

I can't click the cog icon, the go back icon and the show password icon in the login screen. Anyone know how to fix this. Please note that I have no trouble typing the password and pressing enter to log in.

Comment: @PRATAP It is a fresh install and I did not configure anything. I don't even know how to...

Comment: @PRATAP I will try the command. I did download the iso on 24th April 2020.

Comment: @PRATAP Will this make me lose anything? For example, installed packages?

Comment: @PRATAP Command didn't work.

Comment: @PRATAP `gnome-shell --version` is `GNOME Shell 3.36.1` and `gdm3 --version` is `GDM 3.34.1`

Comment: yup I have the same values.. but its working fine.. mine is 23rd April 2020 ISO.. If you have time, try to install the OS with that ISO and see.. but its not the rite way to solve.. out of my knowledge..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107784/discussion-between-sasuke-uchiha-and-pratap).

Comment: @PRATAP That is the same ISO that I used.

Comment: Ok, can you run `sudo apt update` and then reboot. Did you run this command before?

Comment: @PRATAP Come to chat.

Comment: @PRATAP didn't work. Output in chat.